# ExtJs - Tree Drag Drop - Set the newly dragged node to be the selected one

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

Using ExtJS 4, a tree panel and a drag drop..

I'm trying set the newly dragged node to be selected...
something like:

```
viewConfig: {
    listeners : {
        drop: function (node, data, view, ddel, item) {
            this.getSelectionModel().select(data.record);
        }
    }
}
```

This obviously doesn't work, can anybody give me some pointers?

Thanks

Sam

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried listening to the `add` event on the TreePanel?

Comment: no, I will give this a try. the problem I have is that the node is not "added" by the time the drop event is fired.  I can set the root node to be current, but not the newly dragged one.  will try first thing monday.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `treepanel > treeview` in controller query to add drop and beforedrop listeners.